# Home Button in Home Screen App android

Tags: android

I am working on app which will serve as Home Screen Lock. The app will support only 4.1 and above versions. The issue is handling the Home Button. I understand that we cannot override/disable Home Button, so it has to be handled a different way. I have been struggling for almost 2 weeks and tried many umpteenth ways but none of them working as expected. Main Activity is the one which will be on top and user need to enter his set password here to unlock the device. I have set my MainActivity as Home so the user is prompted to select between default launcher and my app. So expected action is to select my app as Launcher 'always'. Also I have set an flag in broadcast receiver whenever MainAcitivity is started. This flag is used in MainActivity to launch system Launcher in case MainActivity isn't started by broadcast receiver. 
Everything is working fine till this point and approach. Issue is when I click on my app to change password or access other features, it doesn't open the app and opens the system launcher. The reason is it checks the flag in Main Activity and since it is not started by broadcast receiver, it doesn't launch MainActivity now and starts the system launcher. Below are code snippets:

Manifest File:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:excludeFromRecents="true"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My Broadcast Receiver

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            AppSession.getInstance().setReceiverCall(true);
            MainActivity.isStarted = true;
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
```

Main Activity where I check the flag and start the system launcher. I amy doing this on onResume

```
if (!MainActivity.isStarted) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackageName, mName));
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

mPackageName & mName are system launcher name.

I tried other approaches as well but only one of the thing is resolved. Either home button is handled correctly and then my app isn't launched. If app is launched then on Home button press from anywhere it always brings my MainActivity on top.

I know this is doable as its done in many ScreenLock apps but somehow I am missing something. Please advise.